# Getting different group values in regex seperated by square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# win form project, I have this regex:

```
^(\[00\])(\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$){1,5}
```

For matching this string:

```
[00][-][300000][20130202200417][1562000]$[-][300000][20140202200417][1562000]$
```

It works well, but I want to get each value in `[]` be in separate groups. Bby this regex the groups will be like this:

```
[00]
[-][300000][20140202200417][1562000]$
-
300000
20140202200417
1562000
```

But I want the second value to be in separate groups like:

```
[-]
[30000]
[20140202200417]
[1562000]
```

So the final result would be:

```
[00]
[-]
[30000]
[20140202200417]
[1562000]
[-]
[300000]
[20140202200417]
[1562000]
```

Comment: Have a look at Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm). It is a useful, interactive way to work on regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect by making the outer group [*non-capturing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#noncapturing_group):

```
^(\[00\])(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$){1,5}
//        ^^
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/oVSn92)

**EDIT:** (in response to an edit of the question)

To capture results of repetitions `{1,5}` into a separate group under its own number you need to "unroll" the expression manually, i.e. repeating it five times, with question mark after the last four (i.e. replace `(?:...)` with `(?:...)(?:...)?(?:...)?(?:...)?(?:...)?` chain).

```
@"^(\[00\])(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$)(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$)?(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$)?(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$)?(?:\[([+-])\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d{14})\]\[(\d+)\]\$)?"
```

The expression becomes big and even less readable, but it does what you want to achieve.

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/Lz5mTi)

Comment: @Elahe It worked perfectly for me - please take a look at the demo that I added, which shows the groups before and after the change. Note that in both cases I skip group zero, because it always contains the entire match.

Comment: I think u didnt get me right, I changed my question, thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
\[(\d+|[-+])\]
```

Its result is as u want.